# Viewmodel binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why am I unable to display the values from my viewmodel like this?

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mailings.ScheduledTime)
```

I'm getting the following error:

*The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage*

My view is using

```
@model List<App.Models.ScheduledMailingsViewmodel>
```

Viewmodels

```
public class MailingViewModel
{
    public string ScheduledTime { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ScheduledMailingsViewmodel
{
    public List<MailingViewModel> Mailings { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ScheduledMailingsViewmodel vm = new ScheduledMailingsViewmodel();
    vm.Mailings = new List<MailingViewModel>();

    using (db)
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var command = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "dbo.GetMailingSchedules";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", "somevalue"));
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var rdr = (command.ExecuteReader());

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            vm.Mailings.Add(new MailingViewModel { ScheduledTime = rdr[0].ToString(), Title = rdr[1].ToString() });
        }
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: item.Mailings is a list.  You need to iterate it.

Comment: How can I do that? @foreach (var item in Model)  doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending viewmodel from controller but in view using list of viewmodel `@model List<App.Models.ScheduledMailingsViewmodel>`. simply use `@model App.Models.ScheduledMailingsViewmodel`.

Comment: Thank you! This together with the suggestion by Manoz below worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This-

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mailings.ScheduledTime)
```

Should be changed to -

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Mailings.ToList()){

 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScheduledTime)

}
```

Comment: @CookieMonster, Great! Keep it up.